# PHP: проверить значения массива на пустоту

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно проверить массив на пустые значения?

Например,

```
$test = array('');
```

Если значения массива будут содержать разное количество пробелов, то как проверить и исключить ключи с пустыми значениями?

Спасибо!

Comment: использовать trim  и empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вообщето можно вызвать функцию `array_filter($array)` без callback функции и она отчистит массив от значений `null,false,''`

Answer (score 1):

вот так

```
   foreach ($playerlist as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) { //проверяем если пустой
           unset($playerlist[$key]);
        }
    }
```

если весь массив пустой

```
if (empty($playerlist)) {
   //empty array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция array_filter может помочь

```
array_filter($test, 'remove_empty');

function remove_empty($v) {
  return trim($v) == $v;
}
```